# How to get BIOS serialnumber with WMIC command

Tags: command-line, bios, wmic

Whenever I use the command line below

> wmic bios get serialnumber

It outputs the BIOS Serial number with my laptop.

However, I've tried that command line to get BIOS serial number with my company's PC, I didn't work a bit.

Here was the output:

```
C:\Users\companypc>wmic bios get serialnumber
SerialNumber
System Serial Number
```

So how can I get the BIOS Serial with that problem...

Comment: Not all computers have a serial number that is accessible via the SMBIOS, especially older ones.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: so how can I get it with command line only as the CPU-Z does?

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed a board, and also not all BIOS codes are actually pre-entered. In that case it is necessary to boot into the BIOS of a machine with that issue, and enter it manually (from reading it off of the hardware itself.)

In other words, if the machine is not very old, the response you are getting is the default response when no value is set (null).

Comment: After doing this, the machine in question should then work with the wmic command.

Comment: There is also the possibility WMIC command may not be working properly. Microsoft has a tool to fix it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684

Answer (score 0):

This exact question was answered in the Super User forum. See https://superuser.com/a/783271/399852 for the answer by [Hennes](https://superuser.com/users/121352/hennes).